# What package contains RxBinding WidgetObservable?

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

What package contains WidgetObservable? I added all possible packages from JakeWharton/RxBinding but WidgetObservable still not available in the code

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:0.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-leanback-v17:0.4.0'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WidgetObservable` among others was superseded by i.e. `RxView`. The ["WidgetObservable and ViewObservable have been rolled into (and improved in) RxBinding"](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/280) issue states that:

> This entire library is the replacement. For example,
>   RxView.clicks(view) provides the click events for any view.